# How to handle modules in an asynchronous app in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop

```
for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
  if (users[i].access_token !== undefined) {
    var syncer = require('dropsite_server/dbox_sync');
    var client = dboxApp.client(users[i].access_token);
    var websites_to_sync = [];
    syncer.doSync(client, users[i].website, users[i].access_token.uid);
  }
}
```

In syner.doSync I have some asynchronous function calls. And yes for performance reasons I want to keep them asynchronous. The issue is, that the syncer object is just a reference, so while doSync is working, the for-loop continues to run, which then changes the variables.

Right now the surrounding for loop has only two elements, result is, only the last element gets processed, but not only once, but actually twice.

The solution would be to make syncer a proper object, but somehow I fail. To get a better understanding of what the code in syncer looks like, here the beginning:

```
/**
* This here is the sync module. User needs to provide. All this module does,
* is sync from a users dropbox to a local path
*/
var dbox = require("dbox");
var fs = require("fs");
var async = require("async");

var allow_downloads = true;
var allow_local_deletes = true;

var client = null;
var saved_sync_data = null;
var sync_data_path = global.config.sync_data_file;
var uid = null;
var remote_sync_dirs = null;

//var sync_data_file = ".dropbox_sync_data";

var errors = [];

var queue = async.queue(doTask, 1);

exports.doSync = function (clientIn, website_domain, _uid) {
    client = clientIn;
    uid = _uid; 
    sync_data_path = sync_data_path + "_" + uid;
    remote_sync_dirs = website_domain;
    async.series(
      [
        readSyncDataFile,
        startSync
      ]);
}
/**
 * Start the Sync
 * @param  dbox client This is a dbox client
*/

function startSync() {
  console.log("get remote delta for website: " + remote_sync_dirs)
  getRemoteDelta();
}
```

Comment: `var syncer = require('dropsite_server/dbox_sync')` will always return the same object (the module), so every call to doSync overwrites your module-scope variables: `client`, `uid`, and `remote_sync_dirs`. It's not clear why you're using those variables  that way at all, since you've only included part of the module, so its going to be hard to offer you detailed solutions.

Comment: Yep. I think that's the issue. I was under the impression, that a module is equal to an object, which I figured now is not the case. So I guess I can either make a proper object and make the variables internal variables or make a stack...

Answer (score 0):

var declarations are not scoped to loops, and should be made at the top of file/function

```
var syncer = require('dropsite_server/dbox_sync')
  , client
  , websites_to_sync = [] //what is this used for?

for (var i = 0; i < users.length; ++i) {
  if (users[i].access_token !== undefined) {
    client = dboxApp.client(users[i].access_token)
    syncer.doSync(client, users[i].website, users[i].access_token.uid);
  }
}
```

The reason the last item gets processed twice is that the doSync function sets module level variables that get overwritten each time you call it.

The way to fix this is to pass the variables to the function instead

```
exports.doSync = function (client, website_domain, uid) {
  sync_data_path = sync_data_path + "_" + uid
  remote_sync_dirs = website_domain

  async.series([
      readSyncDataFile.bind(null, client, website_domain, uid) 
    , startSync.bind(null, client, website_domain, uid) 
  ])
}

function startSync(client, website_domain, uid) {
  ...
}
function readSyncDataFile(client, website_domain, uid) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: I completely rewrote my module now, making it more of a complete object than a collection of functions. Working as expected now. Coming from a PHP/Java world, I'm still having some struggles understanding the Class/Object concept in Javascript... I'll get there eventually.